# Android http json response is coming in pieces

Tags: android, http, post, response, wireshark

I have a problem - I am trying to make a POST request from my app, but it always drop IOexception error on response(like response code, message etc...).

I made that POST request (what i am trying to make from my app) from my PC and I used `WIRESHARK` to see the response, but the response comes in multiple PIECES, not in one as usual.

In my app I use httpulrconnection in acync task.

How do I manage to catch all of the response?

I've added a pics of my `WIRESHARK` file and make it red which contains the response:

[Wireshark http post with response in pieces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LntPR.png)

Comment: Are you trying to load image? Can you provide response headers? I see your are trying to communicate with local WEB-server. Are you correctly set that WEB-server? Maybe you have a problem not in android app.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how anything over a networks is working. 
The data is splitted into smaller packets which will get routed through the network. The maximum of the packet size is defined by the different hops in the network.

In most cases those packets are something like 1460bytes of actual payload.
TCP will make this packet-handling transparent, as it is a protocol on top of this raw layer. So normally you shouldn't take care of this.

If you want to see the whole response (like your application will see it), you can view single tcp streams in wireshark:
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html

**Edit**
The errors you are seeing don't have anything to do with the packaging.